# domain class backend i frontend different projects

Tags: rest, share, frontend, backend, api-design

My question is, what could be the best approach for this specific case?

We have a REST API and multiple clients, such as mobile apps, a front-end and a back-end.

The last two clients are written in with the same language as the REST API.

There are some classes like domain classes or constants that are the same for the clients and the REST API. How can be share it? what do you think could be the best pattern to share it? I want to maintain the independence between the different services and clients.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when designing a public API you'll also provide some documentation. For example, a Type enumeration that's used by the API, and which will probably need to get duplicated on the client side - that's all there is to it, really.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, https://realm.io/ is an attempt to solve this issue for sharing data models between backend and mobile.